# Is it possible to have multiple traefik front-ends using the Service Fabric provider?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, traefik

I'd like my Service Fabric service to be fronted by two separate front-ends; one for internal addressing using a `PathPrefixStrip` rule and one for external addressing using a `Host` rule (because internally the Host value will be something else which is shared with other services).

It looks as if current [Labels syntax for the Service Fabric Traefik provider](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/servicefabric/) only supports a single front-end to be defined and that adding multiple rules will *AND* them together instead of *OR*-ing them.

Is that correct?

For example, I can achieve this using the `[file]` provider:

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend1"
  passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.public]
    rule = "Host:mydomain.localhost"
  [frontends.frontend2]
  backend = "backend1"
  passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.frontend2.routes.internal]
    rule = "Host:localhost;PathPrefixStrip:/test/"
```

Note that the Service Fabric provider reference is at: https://github.com/containous/traefik-extra-service-fabric

Comment: Note: Have added a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik-extra-service-fabric/issues/37)